# AuditingEntityListener junit cannot find context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity and would like to implement Audit and AuditHistory, both works but while unit testing Application context is null.

**The Entity**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EntityListeners(UserListener.class)
public class User extends BaseModel<String> {
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirm;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

**UserListener**

```
public class UserListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(User target) {
        perform(target, INSERTED);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(User target) {
        perform(target, UPDATED);
    }

    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove(User target) {
        perform(target, DELETED);
    }

    @Transactional(MANDATORY)
    void perform(User target, Action action) {
        EntityManager entityManager = BeanUtil.getBean(EntityManager.class);
        if(target.isActive()){
            entityManager.persist(new UserAuditHistory(target, action));
        }else{
            entityManager.persist(new UserAuditHistory(target, DELETED));
        }

    }
}
```

**UserAuditHistory**

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class UserAuditHistory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_user_history"))
    private User user;

    @CreatedBy
    private String modifiedBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedDate;

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private Action action;

    public UserAuditHistory() {
    }

    public UserAuditHistory(User user, Action action) {
        this.user = user;
        this.action = action;
    }
}
```

**BeanUtil for getting and setting context**

```
@Service
public class BeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

Now the Junit where I get null pointer exception on the context from the above BeanUtil class in getBean() method.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserRepositoryTest{

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void whenFindAll_theReturnListSize(){

        entityManager.persist(new User("jk", "password", "password2", null));
        assertEquals(repository.findAll().size(), 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved the problem, in the test class

@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

inside the test method called

```
BeanUtil beanUtil = new BeanUtil();
beanUtil.setApplicationContext(context);
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you're not using spring's AOP, but the static context:

```
private static ApplicationContext context;
```

It's null, because not creating `@Bean` leads to unproxied objects. The solution would be to `@Autowire` it.